# Creating directories from an input file

Tags: unix, awk, scripting, mkdir

I have below mentioned directories in an input file and i need them to create in a loop.

data/app_rt_ws/Request/2017_06_27
data/app_rt_ws/Response/2017_06_19
data/app_rt_ws/RTWS
data/app_rt_ws/SDP
data/edge/response/9-20-2016
data/edge/response/9-22-2016

Problem is that  i don't need the directories in the yyyy_mm_dd or dd-mm-yyyy format which get created at run time on the server. I need them to be discarded and have the rest of the static path of the  directories created.

I am using below mentioned code but can't seem to figure out how to omit the above mentioned part

```
for i in `cat /tmp/inputfile.txt`
do
echo $i
cd /opt/app/app
awk '/date_year/{print $1}' (need to filter out the entries with date)
mkdir -p $i ( need to create rest of the directories)
done
```

Comment: the format of the date in your input file are not consistent. Is that possible to distinguish the year only using 201X? and dd-mm-yyyy should be mm-dd-yyyy in your case. right?

Comment: And is it correct that there are lines without and with date but you want to create directories from both?

Comment: @CWLiu the date format is not consistent. that's the way on production. i tried using `cat /tmp/inputfile.txt | grep -v [0-9]$` to filter out the entries where date was mentioned.

Comment: @JFS31 no, i only need to keep the entries where directory values are without date format

Answer (score 0):

You could use the bash string substitutions to get rid of the date.

```
for i in `cat /tmp/inputfile.txt`
do
echo $i
cd /opt/app/app
if [[ $i =~ [0-9] ]]; then
mkdir -p ${i%/*}
else
mkdir -p $i
fi
done
```

The substitution cuts off everything after the last / so the date is gone.

However if you just want all the ones without numbers then you could do:

```
for i in `cat /tmp/inputfile.txt`
do
echo $i
cd /opt/app/app
if [[ $i =~ [0-9] ]]; then
:
else
mkdir -p $i
fi
done
```

Output of the second version:

```
data/app_rt_ws/RTWS
data/app_rt_ws/SDP
```

I hope this is what you looked for :)

Comment: if there are any numeric in the file but not the date format, your script would misidentify it.

Comment: That is right. But regarding the input I was given it works.

Comment: But if I have a good Idea to make it more robust I will do that :)

Comment: Shell fundamentals: 1) Never use deprecated backticks to execute a command, use `$(command)` instead. 2) Never use `for i in $(command)` to loop setting file names, use `while IFS= read -r i` instead. 3) Never leave shell variables unquoted `echo $i`, always quote them instead `echo "$i"`. Those are absolutely basic shell programming rules, see any shell programming intro for details.

Comment: Hello Ed, thank you for the input. I copied most of the loop from the question so I was not changing anything there. But still, your points are very good.

Answer (score 0):

You may modify your script as followed,

```
for i in `awk '$0 !~ (/[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-20[0-9]{2}/ && /20[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{1,2}_[0-9]{1,2}/){print}' inputfile.txt`;
do
  echo $i
  cd /opt/app/app
  mkdir -p $i
done
```

And the output of the `awk` command is like this,

```
$ awk '$0 !~ (/[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-20[0-9]{2}/ && /20[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{1,2}_[0-9]{1,2}/){print}' inputfile.txt 
data/app_rt_ws/RTWS
data/app_rt_ws/SDP
```

Comment: Shell fundamentals: 1) Never use deprecated backticks to execute a command, use `$(command)` instead. 2) Never use `for i in $(command)` to loop setting file names, use `while IFS= read -r i` instead. 3) Never leave shell variables unquoted `echo $i`, always quote them instead `echo "$i"`. Those are absolutely basic shell programming rules, see any shell programming intro for details.

Comment: Thanks for these tips, I will keep these valuable info in mind.

Answer (score 0):

With bash for regexp matching:

```
$ cat tst.sh
while IFS= read -r path; do
    if [[ $path =~ /([0-9]{4}(_[0-9]{2}){2}|([0-9]{1,2}-){2}[0-9]{4})$ ]]; then
        path="${path%/*}"
    fi
    echo mkdir -p "$path"
done < "$1"

$ ./tst.sh file
mkdir -p data/app_rt_ws/Request
mkdir -p data/app_rt_ws/Response
mkdir -p data/app_rt_ws/RTWS
mkdir -p data/app_rt_ws/SDP
mkdir -p data/edge/response
mkdir -p data/edge/response
```

Remove the `echo` once you've tested and are happy with the result. Check the regexp - you said you wanted to match `dd-mm-yyyy` but then your input contained dates as `d-mm-yyyy` so idk what you really wanted and so I guessed you'd be happy with 1 or 2 digits, hence `[0-9]{1,2}`.

With other shells use a case statement or similar to match the date at the end of line as a globbing pattern. You do NOT need to call an external tool to do this check.

Using:

```
for i in `some command`
```

is always to be avoided because it breaks when the output of `some command` contains spaces and it's using deprecated backticks instead of modern notation `$(some command)`, and doing:

```
echo $i
```

is always to be avoided because you should ALWAYS quote your shell variables (`echo "$i"`) unless you have a specific reason not to so as to avoid accidental word splitting and file name generation.